# Google Plus api calls not authenticated

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm developing a prototype with two simple pages and google plus integration. I have two pages, first one with a "login" button, the second one with a link. When the user clicks on the login button, I am calling:

```
var params = {"client_id":"<client_id>", "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"}; 
gapi.auth.authorize(params, signinCallback);
```

The `signinCallback` looks like this:

```
var signinCallback = function(authResult) {
  if (authResult['access_token']) {
    gapi.auth.setToken(authResult);

    gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
      var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({
        'userId': 'me',
        'collection': 'visible'
      });

      request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      });
    });

  } else if (authResult['error']) {
      console.error('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
```

So when the user clicks the button, signs in and provides permissions to the app, I'm storing the token and making a people list call. This all works perfect.

My problem is when I navigate to the second page and try to make the same call I made before:

```
gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
  var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({
    'userId': 'me',
    'collection': 'visible'
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
  });
});
```

The call fails with the error: `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.`

I thought when I did "setToken" after signing up originally, I wouldn't have to continue authenticating every single subsequent call, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If these are truly two different pages (as opposed to one page that has made some AJAX or other calls to your server to get additional data), then each page has a completely different JavaScript environment. This means that the `gapi` object is a different copy on each page, and the authentication you've set on the first page hasn't been set on the `gapi` object on the second page. You are not setting a token for the session - you're setting it on a specific JavaScript object.

If you are using something like the [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/), you could put the button on each page, and each page would get its own token when the user visits it, but this is somewhat inefficient, since it also means a round-trip to the server each time.

You could probably also do something like put the authentication token into temporary/session local storage, but you should be careful in this case that the token can not leak out and cause you a security issue.

There are other potential solutions, but it really boils down to how you intend to use the authenticated user as part of your client.